# Differentiation Proving

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Can someone please help me solve this question. Provide a hint?

If $$\cos\frac x 2\cos\frac x 4\cos\frac x 8\cdots=\frac{\sin x}x$$ then prove that $$\frac{\sec^2(x/2)}4 + \frac{\sec^2(x/4)}{16} +\cdots = \csc^2 x - \frac1{x^2}.$$

Comment: "... and provide all the steps". You want other people to completely do your work?

Comment: I tried solving the question multiple times. But yes, I should've just asked for a hint and not the steps. Sorry.

Comment: What does this have to do with differentiation?

Comment: This question was there in my assignment booklet under the differentiation topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Observe that for $m\ne0,$
$$\int\sec^2my\ dy=\frac{\tan my}m+C,\int\tan(my)\ dy=\frac{\ln|\sec my|}m+K=-\frac{\ln|\cos y|}m+K$$

As  $A=B\implies \log_cA=\log_cB,$ apply logarithm base $e$

Differentiate either side twice wrt $x$